# AngularJS Firebase Register Form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm currently developing an AngularJS/Firebase web application.

I have successfully implemented Firebase authentication, the user is able to register and log into the application.

The user data is stored within the Firebase > Login & Auth section - like normal.

The problem: The register form has an additional input field labeled Name - how do I send Name and Email information to Firebase > Data ?

I tried implementing two forms, one to register then one for profile data but ideally I would prefer on form to process everything!

Any help/advice would help massively!

**HTML**

```
<form layout="column" ng-submit="authentication.register()">
    Register
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" ng-model="authentication.user.name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" ng-model="authentication.user.email" placeholder="Email" type="email">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" ng-model="authentication.user.password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Register">
  </form>
```

**Controller**

```
(function(angular, undefined) {
  "use strict";
  var am = angular.module('virtual-fitting');
  // Beginning
  am.controller('authenticationCtrl', function(Auth, $state) {
    var self = this;
    self.user = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    };
    self.register = function() {
      Auth.$createUser(self.user).then(function(user) {
        self.login();
      }, function(error) {
        self.error = error;
      });
    };
  });
  // End
})(angular);
```

**Service**

```
(function(angular, undefined) {
  "use strict";
  var am = angular.module('virtual-fitting');
  // Beginning
  am.factory('Auth', function($firebaseAuth, FirebaseUrl){
    var ref = new Firebase(FirebaseUrl);
    var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);
    return auth;
  });
  // End
})(angular);
```

**App**

```
am.constant('FirebaseUrl', 'https://virtual-fitting-app.firebaseio.com/');
```

Comment: Where is your code attempting to store the `name`? Not seeing it. Also, storing user profiles is [covered in the guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing).

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**: Updating to Firebase 3.0 API.

Firebase login is stored on a separate server than your Firebase database.

You need to save the output from the Login server to your database. But, don't save passwords.

Try using a service that knows how to save users to the Firebase database. It only needs to use the regular Firebase library since it's not synchronize data, only saving it.

**[Here's a complete JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/vokalenelu/edit?html,js,output).**

```
(function(angular) {
  var config = {
     apiKey: '<your-api>',
     authDomain: '<your-auth>',
     databaseURL: '<your-db>/',
     storageBucket: '<your-storage>'
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);      
  angular
   .module('virtual-fitting', ['firebase']);
   .constant('FirebaseUrl', config.databaseURL)
   .service('Users', UserService)
   .config(function($firebaseRefProvider, FirebaseUrl) {
     $firebaseRefProvider.registerUrl({
        default: FirebaseUrl,
        users: FirebaseUrl + 'users'
     });
   });


  function UserService($firebaseRef) {
    this.save = function(user) {
      $firebaseRef.users.child(user.uid).set(user);
    };
  }

}(angular));
```